# Too many problems with GRUB2; need factory reset, but cannot fresh install

Tags: grub2, boot-loader, lubuntu

An update corrupted my GRUB, so it takes extra-long to boot my computer since I have to go through the lengthier option via recovery mode.

I want to back up my files on Dropbox and restore the whole system to factory defaults, if that terminology can apply to Linux.

However, I have to avoid the options of things like reinstalling from a USB or Live CD because in my present circumstance it's not possible for me to do that.

After uploading to Dropbox, I want to restore the whole distro to the condition it was in when I had my initial fresh install, and work from there.

How do I accomplish that?

Comment: Are you able to boot your system, yes or not?

Comment: Yes, but it usually takes multiple resets to get to the recovery mode menu, and the indirect boot from there takes an annoyingly long time, far longer than I care to keep tolerating.

Comment: Are you saying you can't use a CD or USB at all? There are other options available, like PXE (network boot) or debootstrap, but neither are for the faint of heart. How much experience do you have with Linux? Do you have any unallocated space on your hard drive, or did you use the full disk when you set up Lubuntu?

Comment: Also... Are you certain this is a GRUB issue?  It does not sound like one to me.  Have you tried reinstalling grub through `grub-install`?

Comment: Aside from not being able to obtain a CD or USB in my current condition, the primary obstacle is that since I'm homeless, I depend on wifi for Internet, and it takes too long to DL a distro. I can't maintain a connection long enough. As such, I'm stuck modifying what I've got, for now. I don't have much experience with Linux, and I use the full disk when I set up Lubuntu, though would probably know how to fiddle around with the disk partitioner.

Comment: Ok, gotcha. You don't live in northern NJ by chance, do you? I'd be happy to help if so (my email is [here](http://fieldeffect.info/wp/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/signature.gif) if yes). If this is your only computer, I'm a little apprehensive to give you directions that could put you in a position where you might not have _any_ computer, because this stuff could leave your computer in a worse state than it's in now, if you aren't 100% certain what's happening.

Comment: Or, if you have some nearby location that I can send a USB flash drive to you-- a church or whatever, send it to my e-mail address and I'll drop one in the mail on Monday with Lubuntu on it.  I think you're going to need some kind of physical external drive to do this.  AFAIK, it's not possible to resize a partition while it's in use; and even if you have a free partition, making it usable with [debootstrap](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/installation-guide/ia64/linux-upgrade.html) is tricky.

Comment: I live in TX, and I'd rather not take advantage of your kindness by imposing the expense of a USB on you. I found a troubleshooting guide where I may be able to try a few other things. Otherwise, I can tolerate the boot problem for now. I've got some good job prospects, so I should be able to afford a USB shortly.

Comment: @Benjamin It is certainly not too much trouble-- so if you change your mind, definitely send me an e-mail. I've taken more than my own fair share of help when I've been in rough spots, so don't hesitate. I'm afraid trying fixes might brick your computer and you won't be able to get back online.

Comment: BTW - I noticed your [other post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/160586/too-many-problems-with-grub2-need-factory-reset-but-cannot-fresh-install), with the pastebin. You might be able to format your swap partition as ext4, and `debootstrap` that. Once booted you then debootstrap Linux in your main partition. Do you want me to post how to do this?  I need to know what wifi card you have.  Did it "just work" with Lubuntu?  This is not "safe" (hopefully your guide is safer) but might work. The safest way is probably to figure out what's wrong with your boot process & fix it.

Comment: I'll consider these suggestions, but I'm afraid I'll have to drop the issue for now. Aside from being homeless, I've recently become unemployed, so that demands my greatest attention since my money has run out. My computer boots fine, albeit slower due to the GRUB malfunction, but I'll tolerate it since it works.